# NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, геолокация

В это куске кода ошибка NullPointerException

```
     private double format1Location(Location location) {
                if (location == null)
                return location.getLatitude();
                return 0;
}
        private double format2Location(Location location) {
                if (location == null)
                    return  location.getLongitude();
                    return 0 }
          GeoPoint currentLocation = new GeoPoint
 (format1Location(null), format2Location(null), "hhh", "h", 1);
```

Точнее, она с `return  location.getLongitude()` и `return  location.getLatitude();`. Помогите исправить, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ваши глупые вопросы и дальше будут закрывать. Вы задаете уже 4 вопрос, и никак не поймете, что либо идите учите основы языка, либо идите и заплатите кому-нибудь на фриланс бирже.

Comment: Вы вообще сюда https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html заглядывали? Там ведь даже готовый код есть...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка `NullPointerException` значит, что метод ожидает каких то данных, а вместо этого получает НИЧТО - он ничего не может сделать, имея НИЧТО и говорит вам об этом.
Это как вы пришли в магазин и просите продать бубликов, а продавщица вам вместо самих бубликов подает ДЫРКИ от этих бубликов - вот то состояние, в которое вы впадете поняв, ЧТО вам дали и будет`NullPointerException`.
Подумайте, как вы будете пить чай со своей покупкой, а потом  - что делать компилятору, имея такого "программиста", как вы.

Конкретно в вашем случае вы используете метод, который написали САМИ, **СОБСТВЕННЫМИ** руками указали, что требуется объект `Location` и теперь спрашиваете, что туда передавать - это за гранью добра уже .
Не думаете же вы, что вставив `null` ваша проблема чудесным образом решится сама собой и компилятор как то сам догадается за вас.

Если вы не знаете, какого типа данные требуются на вход методу, то посмотрите его сигнатуру в документации, если это метод из `API` ( аналогичную информацию предоставляет IDE, например в Android Studio - `Ctrl+Q` на нужном методе) . Там вы узнаете, что требуется на вход - начинайте узнавать, как получить данные такого типа.

Лирическое отступление далее - не ответ на вопрос, но видеть такое я больше не могу, а в комментарий все не входит. Прошу простить.

Слушай друг, вот ты обижаешься, что тебе не помогают. Ты должен понять, что на том уровне, на котором ты сейчас "программируешь", тебе никто не поможет в паре предложений.
Тебе нужно систематизированное знание не конкретно по этой проблеме, а по умению программировать вообще. Такое знание можно получить из учебников, курсов и пр. методических источников, но никак из решения этой твоей конкретной роблемы.
Ты просто не понимаешь, что ты делаешь и как надо делать. Даже, если тебе скажут решение конкретно этой проблемы (хотя его уже раз пять давали), ты через пару строчек уткнешся в другую, не менее нелепую по факту, но не преодолимую для тебя.
Если ты надеешся копипастом чужих идей и дониманием по каждой проблеме на разных ресурсах, вроде этого, написать какую то программу, то забудь - нельзя просто так взять и написать приложение, не зная языка программирования, на котором ты пишешь.

Если ты думаешь - начну что то делать и по ходу научусь (есть любители такого обучения программированию, которые по факту, как правило, просто не хотят ничего уметь, а думают, что так как то проскочут) , то ты УЧИСЬ уже - получил проблему, узнавай в чем причина, почему появилась, как исправить - ЧИТАЙ больше , узнавай новое, а НЕ ПИШИ о своих неудачах.

С таким подходом, в общем, ты свою программу никогда не напишешь.

Comment: спасибо..) да понимаю я последнюю часть, но учить нужно блин долго, как кто-то писал, что программисты учатся 5 лет... Ну я и пытаюсь как-то выкручиваться, Хоть на бытовом уровне владеть.Что-то то я понимаю...Кстати, правильно написали, что я тыркаюсь на разных ресурсах и подчерпываю оттуда...Но я чужие идеи не беру, я на основе чужих придумываю свое, пытаюсь доделать...Вобщем, спасибо...Хоть кто-то не орет, а нормально говорит хоть(посмотрите, какая у металургуса бомбежка(металургус, извините)).

Answer (score 7):

```
if (location == null)
                return location.getLatitude();
```

Тут не язык подучить надо. А хотя хотя бы азы формальной логики, на самом примитивном, бытовом уровне.

Comment: оупс... ну это понятно, что должно быть 'if (location != null)'...

Comment: Мне непонятно, что надо поставить в строчке GeoPoint currentLocation = new GeoPoint
 (format1Location(null), format2Location(null), "hhh", "h", 1); вместо null

Comment: Зачем вам вообще эти `format1Location` и `format2Location`?

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно же, что вместо `null` необходимо передавать объект [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html).
Получить его можно используя класс [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html). В документации все подробно описано что и как передать.